# React-Native problem with "expo-localization" on iOS

Tags: react-native, localization, expo

I have problem with **expo-localization**. On Android it is working normally, but on my IOS emulator I am getting this error (viz. screen).
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-localization

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAozL.png

I get an error whenever I call a parameter from a library.

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';

function getDeviceCountry() {
  let country = "US";
  console.log(Localization.locale);
  return country.toLowerCase();
}
```

I tried get info about my **permission.localization** on emulator, but I got granted.
I don't know what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the iOS simulator.

For me it helped to set a language & region in the iOS Simulator. Go to **Settings > General > Language and region** and update **region** setting

I found the solution here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5735#issuecomment-534063072